# FIX protocol engine for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, protocols, quickfix, fix-protocol

Can anyone recommend a FIX Engine (commercial or open source) for use with Delphi?

Is it possible to use QuickFIX with Delphi?

Comment: According to [QuickFix's project page](http://www.quickfixengine.org/): "API's are available for C++, .NET, Python and Ruby". From that list the C++ Api's are the ones most likely to be useful. Did you investigate?

Comment: @Cosmin, the C++ API uses classes and namespaces, which aren't trivial to import into a non-C++ environment. (They're not trivial to import into a C++ environment, either, if the C++ environment isn't identical to the DLL's development environment.)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at **B2BITS FIX Antenna**. There are two possible options:

- FIX Antenna C++ has ANSI C interface that can be used in Delphi (there is a sample in the package)

http://www.b2bits.com/trading_solutions/fix_engines/fix_engine_cpp.html

- FIX Antenna .NET can be used in Delphi .NET (there is again a sample in the package; also programmer's guide contains Delphi.NET samples)

http://www.b2bits.com/trading_solutions/fix_engines/fix_enginenet.html

Feel free to contact me directly if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

QuickFix is a C++ project.

Both Python and Ruby use SWIG to expose the C++ classes as native Python and Ruby classes.

The .NET wrapper sounds like a mix of C++ and C# code.

It's not possible to import C++ classes within Delphi directly. You'll have to use a "flat API" conversion, exposing all C++ methods as plain C declarations, in order to import external structures and functions in a Delphi unit.

To my knowledge, there is no such "flat API" of QuickFIX available, and no SWIG version able to generate Delphi code. You'll have to write your own wrapper in C++, or perhaps write your own FIX implementation in Delphi.

The only FIX library I know for Delphi is the one from http://www.b2bits.com - it did exist some years ago, but I'm not sure it's still sold/maintained - they seems to maintain only a DotNet version. Worth asking them for pricing and availability, in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

One way to integrate the protocol with Delphi would be building a .Net or Java bridge, for example:

- use the .Net C# implementation to build a small application to communicate with the FIX side
- then expose methods (and maybe even the objects) of this .Net app over SOAP web services
- use Delphi's web service client code generator to import the SOAP WSDL
- access the web service from the Delphi side

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more of a hack than anything else, but you *could* use the Python QuickFIX bindings in Delphi, via [python4delphi](http://code.google.com/p/python4delphi/).  That's a lot of layers though (Delphi to Python to C++).

Python is an easy language to use, and learn, and it's easy to invoke and create python objects (or native C wrappers that pretend to be python objects) and invoke them directly from the Python4Delphi API.

Barring that, it might be very little work for you to build a procedural (flat) API as ABouchez said. Instead of writing a million functions I would write only the ones I needed, and then implement these simple functions inside a VC++ DLL:

```
   QuickFixInit;
   QuickFixCleanup;
   handle := QuickFixLoadFile(filename)
   QuickFixSaveFile(handle)
   handle2 := QuickFixGetObjectHandle(handle,index,...); 
   QuickFixModifyObjectProperty(handle2, propertyname, propertyvalue );
   QuickFixExecuteSomeAction( handle2, actionname, param1,param2,param3 );
```

The above are just to give you the flavor. I know nothing about the internal API, but what I'm showing you above is that you don't need to conform 100% to the API to write a wrapper. You could probably (if you know C/C++) write a functional wrapper that does what you need, and export it, link it into a DLL, and then import QuickFix.dll into Python with very little (2-4 hours of an expert's time) work, if you know Visual C++ well enough to write a few simple C-style (non OOP) functions that instantiate C++ classes, and invoke C++ methods.

It might be possible to expose the C++ APIs to Delphi via a C++Builder package (BPL) containing QuickFIx, but (a) some source modifications would be required, and (b) the C++ code in QuickFix, or its dependencies, might not build in C++Builder without significant modifications.